# Check read writes in Aerospike using asadm

Tags: aerospike, asadmin

currently i found out that the read write value of each namespace will be stored in log file,

is there there any commands to see these read, writes in Aerospike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I understand the question correctly but if you are looking for the read/write throughput (that get logged on the server under the histogram dumps), you can get them via the asadm `show latencies` command. Refer to [the relevant asadm paragraph](https://docs.aerospike.com/tools/asadm/user_guide/live_cluster_mode_guide#latencies).

You can also see the total number of read / write (broken down by success, not found, error, filtered out, etc..). For example, [client_read_success](https://docs.aerospike.com/reference/metrics#client_read_success). So, from asadm: `show stat like client_read`.